# how to get a string using shell script commands?

Tags: bash, sh

I have a file that contains the following data:

```
__NV__: 1
name: "MEP-UI-CUSTOMER-INFO-TXT"
desc: "MEP Customer Name Information"
fpath: "mep/frontend/ui/primecast/assets/i18n/custom-info.txt"
fdata: "telestra"
```

I want to get the value of fdata (telestra).
How can I achieve using shell scripting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `awk`, `grep`, or `sed` for this task.

Here are a few examples.

Note: the sample data provided has been stored in a file called `sample.txt`

Awk

```
# The NF means the number of fields,
# it is used to print the last field
awk '/fdata/ { print $NF }' sample.txt
"telestra"
```

Grep

```
# Note that this one returns both
# the field label, as well as the value
grep fdata sample.txt
fdata: "telestra"
```

Grep + Sed

```
# The results of grep are piped into
# sed, which then removes the field name
grep fdata sample.txt | sed 's/fdata: //g'
"telestra"
```